# Why do I get this stack overflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm trying to deploy my Java application, but an running into some very odd issues. When I run in eclipse, and when I run on my mac(compiled), I have no issues at all, but them I run on a PC issues arise.

Error(Obfed code):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.InputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at b.a.b.a.c.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.b.b.d.<init>(Unknown Source)
at b.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
at b.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
...
```

Method in error:

```
public static String readStringFromFile(File f) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static void loadSettings() {
  if(Util.getNewFile("pref.txt").exists()) {
      String s = Util.readStringFromFile(Util.getNewFile("pref.txt"));
      String[] tmp2 = s.split("\n");
      for(String tmp0 : tmp2) {
        if(!tmp0.equals("") || !tmp0.startsWith("#")) {
          Main.params.add(tmp0);
        }
      }             
    }
}
```

I had an error like this before, when I was using reflection.
(Jar is launched by refection, if that is important)

Does anyone know whats causing this?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can try increasing the jvm memory with `-Xmx<size>`

Comment: Usually this means your recursive calls are too deeply nested. Do you have any recursion in your program?

Comment: You'd also need to include which JDK version you're running under on the system in error; while Java bugs are relatively rare, they exist.

Comment: You can try increasing the stack size (`-Xss`). But I bet the problem is `b.a.c.f.a` calls itself infinitelly. You probably need to look there.

Comment: @micha I run the program with 1.5 GB of ram, so I doubt thats the issue.

Comment: @Banthar It's odd, the method 'start' will execute, then when it gets to readStringFromFile, the method 'start' will run again.

Comment: I suppose the method `b.a.b.a.c.a` is readStringFromFile. Can you post the method `b.a.c.f.a`? (that one seems to be the problem).

Comment: @Pablo b.a.c.f.a is the method calling readStringFromFile.

Comment: Most likely reasons for occurances of StackOverflow-Errors are too deep or infinite recursions. I bet `b.a.c.f.a` uses recursion. Always avoid recursion and prefer imperative style.

Comment: @FabianBarney No recursions, it's quite odd.

Comment: @user1681891 Well, stacktrace clearly shows that there is recursion. ^^ Just show the code or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: @FabianBarney Added method.

Comment: @user1681891 This is a different method. The one from stacktrace invokes a constructor of `b.a.b.b.d`.

Comment: @Banthar Found the issue, it was a library I was using.